# Использование OUT REF CURSOR в цикле FOR

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть процедура, которая возвращает `REF CURSOR`. Хочу использовать полученный список в цикле `FOR`. Такое возможно?

Пример:

```
  PROCEDURE my_proc_1
  (
    p_var_1  NUMBER
  ) AS
    l_list SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    my_proc_2(out_refcur  => l_list,
              p_var_2     => p_var_1);
    FOR v_var IN l_list
    LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(v_var.col_1);
    END LOOP;
  END my_proc_1;
```

Так работать не будет, но показывает, что я примерно хочу увидеть.

Comment: А что не получается? Устраните ошибки и будет работать.

Comment: @0xdb Говорит, мол, l_list не является переменной или не определена. Не понимаю, что это может значить в данном контексте, ведь я её определил в DECLARE блоке и "наполнил" при вызове процедуры my_proc_2

Comment: А зачем цикл FOR, он же открывает курсор, а он у вас уже открыт? "наполнил" значит открыт.

Comment: @0xdb Потому что он сразу определяет индекс v_var и не надо перечислять где-то его тип :3 Используй в своё удовольствие. Ну и просто я раньше всегда его использовал (FOR), а тут впервые курсор открылся не здесь же, а в другой процедуре. Там еще и набор столбцов может оказаться не всегда один и тот же.

Comment: Вам нужен `fetch l_list into ...`. Он делает то же самое, только не открывает курсор.

Comment: @0xdb Да, я нашел в интернетах пример: `LOOP FETCH occupancy_cur INTO occupancy_rec; EXIT WHEN occupancy_cur%NOTFOUND; END LOOP;` Но при этом, в примере occupancy_rec декларируется как `occupancy_cur%ROWTYPE`, где occupancy_cur - статический курсор. если же я объявлю `l_list_rec l_list%ROWTYPE`, то он ругнется "Описание типа этого выражения незавершено или выполнено не верно". Как определить тогда индекс, не перечисляя всех столбцов (которые не всегда могут быть одни и те же, т.к. запрос в процедуре динамический) - не совсем понятно.

Comment: Никак. Вы же передаёте в FOR запрос и он строит временный rowtype для этого запроса. Вы должны заранее декларировать типы, в которые fetch сможет вернуть данные. Из переменной с открытым курсором вы не сможете декларировать тип данных. Ну или dbms_sql на крайний случай.

Comment: Да, "запрос в процедуре динамический". А цикл FOR это статический SQL. Он поэтому и называется статический потому, что после компиляции ни запросы, ни типы данных для этих запросов больше не меняются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не разобрался, как перенести комментарий 0xdb в ответ (вроде бы раньше была такая функция), поэтому приведу код, в соответствии с ним.

```
 PROCEDURE my_proc_1
  (
    p_var_1  NUMBER
  ) AS
    l_list SYS_REFCURSOR;
    TYPE t_list_rec IS RECORD
      (
        col_1 type_1,
        col_2 type_2,
      );
    v_list_rec t_list_rec;
  BEGIN
    my_proc_2(out_refcur  => l_list,
              p_var_2     => p_var_1);
    LOOP
      FETCH l_list INTO v_list_rec;
      EXIT WHEN l_list%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line(v_list_rec.col_1);
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE l_list;
  END my_proc_1;
```

Comment: _вроде бы раньше была такая функция_ - врооде такой не было, копировали, форматировали и радовались.